# How to implement Chrome forceDarkModeEnabled per site

Tags: css, google-chrome, chromium

I use the chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark enabling the option Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents. It works great for most of sites, with minor glitches in specific cases.

But what i would like to do is to add an option on my own site to the user enable a custom dark mode in any browser.

Is here a way to get the same CSS used on Chrome's "Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents" , so i can implement something very similar on my web site ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://dev.to/albertomontalesi/add-dark-mode-to-your-website-with-just-a-few-lines-of-code-5baf